# Resampling an array fast with numba

Tags: python, repeat, numba

I have a function that takes in an array an returns an upsampled version of it by using linear interpolation between the existing data points. The input array has approximately 5000 elements.
I would also like to implement a version that handles 2d arrays with shape ~(4000, 5000).

Why is this function not faster with numba njit?
It runs superfast on 1d arrays without numba. With numba.njit it takes much longer.
Any advice is much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def sync_sampl(time_series, repeat=10):
    if time_series.ndim == 1:
        time_series = time_series.repeat(repeat)
        # from https://mail.python.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-November/027574.html
        # by Dharas Pothina
        x = time_series
        xtmp = x.copy()
        xtmp[1:] = x[1:] - x[:-1]
        x_idx = np.nonzero(xtmp)[0]
        x_vals = x[x_idx]
        x_new = np.interp(np.arange(len(x)), x_idx, x_vals)
        x_new = x_new[:-(repeat - 1) or None]  # removing last elements to not get straight line at the end.
        return x_new
    else:
        # Implement 2d version here?
        pass
```

Comment: `numba` only helps with things that can be optimized, like loops.  You have no loops.  `numpy` already runs most of its functions in native code.  Your Python here is just plumbing, one step after another.  `numba` can't help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Tim. 
Do you have any tips on how to make this code optimizable by numba, by using loops instead of inbuilt functions?

Comment: What I'm saying is that it might be as fast as it can be.  Have you computed the number of operations here and compared it to the time it actually takes?  Computers are not infinitely fast.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I have not calculated the number of operations, but I understand what you're saying, and why numba cannot help on this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips to make the Numba code faster:

- You can tell to Numba that the input array is **contiguous** (only if it is true) and **pre-compile** the function ahead of time not to pay expensive compilation times at runtime. Here is an example: `@nb.njit('float[::1](float32[::1],int32)')`.
- you can use the option `parallel=True` on `@nb.njit` to execute some Numpy function in **parallel**. However, most functions a not yet running in parallel with it. Still, you can run loops in parallel with that and `nb.prange`.
- As said in the comments, Numba is often good with **loops**. Numba loops are not always faster because the compiled Numpy code tends to be better vectorized than the JIT code from Numba. However, loops enable you to avoid creating/filling/reading **many temporary arrays** making your code *memory-bound*. Well-optimized loops also often help to reduce the number of instructions required to perform a custom operations. In your case, the lines from `xtmp = x.copy()` to `x_vals = x[x_idx]` can be rewritten using one fast memory-efficient parallel loop (and so no temporary buffers).
- Note that you can also use the option `fastmath=True` if you are sure that there is no NaN/+Inf/-Inf/-0 values in your code (and the need for exact IEEE-754 rules like rounding) to improve performance even further. Using 32-bit floats may help too despite the significant loss of precision.